# É possível alterar o valor de um Readonly com condições?

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia. Não achei nada parecido em muitos posts então resolvi questionar pra vocês: é possível alterar o valor de um campo readonly?
Por exemplo, supondo que você tenha dois campos (número 1 e número 2), com os valores 3 e 3, e queira fazer a multiplicação deles aparecer num terceiro campo de readonly com o valor 9 (resultado dessa equação).

Fiz um código e não consegui resultados. A teoria é que se obtém o que está no campo número e, ao usuário modificar, vai alterando o resultado do campo "valor" que mostra a multiplicação por 2. Consigo alterar o campo do número mas meu campo de valor da multiplicação continua nulo.

```
<script>
let numero = document.getElementById("numero");
function valor() {
    let novoValor = 2 * numero;
    $("#valor").val('novoValor');
}
numeroKm.addEventListener('change', valor); 
</script>
```

Comment: Mas se você vai modificar um campo não deveria declara-lo como readonly.

Comment: É porque esse campo fica alterável conforme a pessoa passa por um SELECT, com várias opções. Ai quando chega nessa opção específica, fiz com que aparecesse um campo de número e o campo de resultado ficasse como readonly.

Comment: Queria que esse valor do readonly mantivesse sua propriedade de não ser alterado diretamente pelo usuário, mas mudando seu valor de acordo com o input do lado dele.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

O readolny é somente para o browser do usuário bloquear a edição! Via código vai normal!

No código que está aqui, você usa primeiro a variavel **numero** para obter o campo e depois adiciona o EventListener na **numeroKm**.

Também usa JavaScript puro e JQuery (Sem problemas, desde que tenha JQuery na página rs)

Para obter o valor tem usar **numero.value**

O addEventListener tem que ser adicionado após o carregamento do Elemento em questão! O script deveria estar após ele, ou associado ao evento de window.onload

Assim funcionou:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sem título</title>
<script>    

window.onload = function(){ 

    let campoNumero = document.getElementById("numero");
    let campoValor = document.getElementById("valor");

    campoNumero.addEventListener('change', valor);

    function valor() {

        let novoValor = 2 * campoNumero.value;
        campoValor.value = novoValor;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="numero">
    <input type="text" readonly id="valor">
</body>
</html>
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Show, então meu erro no caso seria a falta do window.onload? Qual seria a propriedade dele? Abraços.

Comment: Basicamente, ele só executa a função, quando todo o DOM estiver carregado! Neste caso, como para definir o addEventListener o elemento precisa estar carregado, resolve, pois TODOS elementos da página estarão carregados ao executá-la. Para funcionar, sem o window.onload, você teria que declarar o script após os inputs!

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi certo a pergunta não há problemas, o atributo [readyonly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly) determina que o elemento seja somente leitura para a interface.

Para o script é indiferente. Veja o exemplo:

```js
let a = document.getElementById("A");
let b = document.getElementById("B");
//res é a referência para um elemento readonly 
let res = document.getElementById("Resultado");

function multiplicar() {
  //O valor do readonly foi modificado
  res.value = Number(a.value) * Number(b.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="A" value="0" />
<span>x</span>
<input type="number" id="B" value="0">
<button onclick="multiplicar()">Multiplicar</button>
<br><br>
<!-- O input a seguir é readonly e não pode ser alterado pelo usuário -->
<label>Total:
   <input type="number" id="Resultado" readonly>
</label>
```

Comment: Show, entendi. Por exemplo, se fosse sem este botão que chama a função, eu poderia utilizar um EventListener que, ao alterar o valor de qualquer uma das duas variáveis, chamasse automaticamente o resultado? Tentei utilizar numero.addEventListener('change', valor); porém aparentemente não está mudando, continua nulo.

Comment: @GustavoS.Rocha Sim, com certeza poderia ser `numero.addEventListener('change', valor);` como poderia ser `numero.addEventListener('input', valor);`

Comment: Infelizmente não estou conseguindo obter o valor no campo de readonly. Veja meu método:
<script>
let numero = document.getElementByName("numero");
let preco = document.getElementByName("preco");
function alterarPreco() {
    preco.value = 2 * Number(numero.value);
}
numero.addEventListener('change', alterarPreco); 
</script>

Comment: @GustavoS.Rocha Edite a pergunta e coloque o HTML junto para que possa analisar o problema como um todo.

Comment: Desculpe a demora, Augusto! O Duda acabou auxiliando da mesma forma que você também me ajudou muito, então acho que não será mais necessário!